# Virtual Network Adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-adapter

I am new in networking and virtualization. I really need assistance on this problem.

**I have a scenario:** there are 4 virtual machines that created through **VirtualBox on WIN7**. 2 of them are centos, 1 of them is windows xp, and 1 of them is windows 2008 server. I created and installed all of them on VirtualBox on my WIN7 physical pc.

**It is expected that** only the windows 2008 server has external internet connection, and other 3 virtual machine will use it to access internet.

I searched on adapter logic (NAT, Bridged, Internal, Host-Only) but didn't get it. How should I select the adapters of VMs to do that? Thanks for help.

Comment: Lets start with what virtual machine software you are using and what host operating system you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound virtualbox 4.3.6 on win7

Comment: Update your question to reflect that information.

Comment: I can ping a website or a client (10.10.10.2) from Server (192.168.1.8), but cannot ping a website from XP client. I am taking `Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.` error. [Please look at my cmd screens](http://s24.postimg.org/hr1amhilh/image.png)

Comment: You cannot ping because the adapter has an entirely different sub-intranet address.  I don't believe you can configure a virtual machine with Virtual Box to share the virtual adapter that is being shared by the host os with another virtual machine.  Even if you could the results would match simply sharing the network adapater of the host os with the other virtual machines also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual Network Adapters](http://superuser.com/questions/696484/virtual-network-adapters)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is basically use the Win2k8 server VM as if it were a proxy or router for the other three VMs, is that right?  In turn, the Win2K8 VM uses the adaptor of the host machine to get out to the Internet.

I would try building the four VMs with Host-Only Networking, and on the 2k8 VM, add an additional interface in Bridged mode.  Then set the default route on the other three to be the (internal) network IP of the 2k8 box.

The VirtualBox help system describes something very close to your scenario in the chapter on Host-Only networking and has more details.